# How to use XenForo's caching mechanism in add-on?

Tags: caching, add-on, xenforo

I'd like to reuse XenForo's internal caching features within the add-on I've written for it. More precisely, I want to cache some string I am outputting within a 'template_hook' listener code.

I tried to let the listener class extend several XenForo-internal classes like `XenForo_Template_Abstract` or `XenForo_Template_Helper_Core` in order to get access to the `_loadTemplateFromCache()` or the `_getModelFromCache()` function, though so far without success.

How to use XenForo's caching mechanism within add-ons?